(1 external) Multiple Displays different scaling for ubuntu
I have exactly the same problem as outlined by our fellow here Different display scale settings -  with the configuration that inbuilt eDP1 connected primary 3840x2160 (Dell XPS 13) scaled at 200% and the external Dell 14inch portable monitor with resolution 1900x1080 scaled at 100%, both connected via usb type c.
It's impossible via ubuntu settings to get different scalings for display. xrandr did not provide a solution via my futile attempts. I'm open to suggestions. I need the external monitor to remain scaled at 100% whereas the built in to be at 200%, and I want to remain with the same resolutions.

Ubuntu 18.04 LTS reached End of Standard Support last year, and is thus off-topic on this site.  You can use ESM/Pro support options (cost maybe involved) if you wish but community support (such as this site) no longer exists, though SE Unix & Linux allow all Ubuntu questions too.  Please see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic as Canonical provide ESM/Pro services.

You've not provided any Ubuntu product/release details; as the version/software you're using can make a huge difference (ie. modern Ubuntu GNOME 4x uses GTK4 which has more options than legacy releases using GTK3/GNOME3).  Your prior ask of this question highlighted GNOME Shell 3.28 or Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

i want it to work independent of Ubuntu release and want to focus on xrandr ... that should be independent of version. @guiverc , I hope this clarifies your question while I appreciate your enthusiasm to have this questions closed down.
